# weblogic domain creation hangs

Tags: ubuntu, weblogic12c

i have an Ubuntu server, I'm connecting to the server with ssh and using  X11 forwarding from  Osx host. I started the config.sh which is located here: /wls12210/oracle_common/common/bin/ this way:

```
sh config.sh  -log=/tmp/wl.log
```

The config wizard shows up in the XQuartz but when I click on next button after i chosed "Basic Weblogic Server Domain Template it's hangs and nothing happens. I checked the log that I setup. This is how it's look like:

```
2015-11-16 14:23:04,188 INFO  [24] com.oracle.cie.domain.template.catalog.impl.OracleHomeLocator - /home/warmhome/wls12210/oracle_common is already in the list
2015-11-16 14:23:08,190 INFO  [12] com.oracle.cie.domain.DomainRegistryWrapper - The domainRegistrydocument object needs to be Initialized
```

There isn't any error, or exception in this log. But notthing happens with the config wizard. I was waiting about 30 minutes.

Could please anybody help me what should I try to do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: For those who stumble over this question... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2564406/4905506, in short - the most probable cause you are running under VM (any VM it seems, in my case it was Hyper-V,) and the secure random generator is too slow. There are a few options, all change secure random source java property.